# How to enter external pdf into quarto book while keeping page layout+numbering

Tags: pdf, latex, pandoc, quarto

Is it possible to add an external pdf into a quarto book and render it into pdf, while still keeping the page numbering of the whole quarto book?

`{{< include figs/examplepdf.pdf >}}` does not seem to work

`\includepdf[]{examplepdf.pdf}` seems only to add the pdf document, but 'as is', not layouted in the quarto book's layout (e.g. page numbering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Quarto contains tools to generate PDF, but not to parse PDFs. The latter would be required to include PDFs the way you imagine, adjusted to the style of the document. The [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package (of which you already mentioned the `\includepdf` command) is likely the closed you can get.